# inoremap <Up> <C-c>gka sometime does not work

Tags: key-bindings

I have put the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
inoremap <Up> <C-c>gka
```

But sometime, instead of moving my cursor, `gka` is inserted as text as I am in insert mode. It seems the `<C-c>` did not work as expected. This behavior appears also with mappings that use `<C-o>` and `<Esc>`.

I don't know if could be related to this config:

```
set timeoutlen=1000
set ttimeoutlen=0
set timeout
set nottimeout
```

I am running on Cygwin mintty

Comment: Set `ttimeoutlen` to a larger value.  Also read `:h i_CTRL-o`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura It does not work even with `ttimeoutlen=20` :(

Comment: Try something like 100...

Comment: @SatoKatsura It does not work even with ttimeoutlen=200

Comment: Actually it works better when `ttimeoutlen=0` but it's far from perfect

Comment: What about trying to use `<Esc>` or `<c-[>`  instead of `<C-c>`?

Comment: I was using `<Esc>` then I switched to `<C-o>` and now I am trying `<C-c>`, but I still have this issue :(

Comment: What are your setting of `timeout` and `ttimeout`? Is this terminal Vim or GVim?  If terminal Vim, what terminal are you running it into?  What OS are you using?  What version of Vim?

Comment: @SatoKatsura I updated my question with the answers to your questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following mapping works fine here:

```
inoremap <up> <c-o>gk
```

Note that [using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-O) you don't need the `a` at the end of your mapping to get back to insert mode. And you should generally [avoid using using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit insert mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80677/what-is-the-difference-between-c-c-and-c-in-vim), as it can break some functionality and plugins.

You could try the following to debug your problem:

### 1) Check if the problem happens in vanilla vim

Start Vim with `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE`. If the problem doesn't happens, it means you have a problem related to some setting/plugin. In this case you could follow the steps at [Vim-FAQ  2.5 - *I have a "xyz" (some) problem with Vim. How do I determine it is a problem with my setup or with Vim?  / Have I found a bug in Vim?*](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5).

### 2) Try to map another key instead of the arrow keys

Still with vanilla Vim, try mapping to a regular key:

```
inoremap a <c-o>gk
```

If the problem doesn't happens, check the instructions at [Vim-FAQ  10.9 - *When I use my arrow keys, Vim changes modes, inserts weird characters      in my document but doesn't move the cursor properly. What's going on?*](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-10.9), which references some relevant options such as `'ttimeoutlen'`.

### 3) Try other terminals/gVim

If nothing else solves the problem, the problem is probably related to your terminal. You could try using another terminal or, even better, gVim (Graphical Vim), which is available on Windows and thus would allow you to avoid Cygwin and any problem related to shell limitations.

Comment: I'll go with `<C-o>` instead of `<C-c>`. The arrows keys are not the problem because I get the same problem with my `<C-y>` and `<C-s>` mapping. I will try with vanilla Vim as well. Related to the latter point, I feel gVim is much more limiting than my Terminal Vim :)

Comment: `because I get the same problem with my <C-y> and <C-s> mapping` - note that these are also composed keys; it would be better to test with a simpler mappings, such as `a` or `b`. About gVim, I'm curious :)    how do you find it more limiting?

Comment: I can quickly access my terminal with `<C-z>` which I do all the time. With my terminal I can enter in real full screen mode (no borders) and there are some mapping that fails on gvim not not on the terminal version (with proper binding). Last but not least, I can use tmux in full screen mode and directly send Python code to my iPython instance.